# Core Plot: How to set xRange/yRange with different scales?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, core-plot

I am wanting to use Altitude for my Y range and Distance for my X range.  Currently this is what I am using:

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange 
                        plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) 
                        length:CPDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(sortedArray.count)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange 
                        plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(min) 
                        length:CPDecimalFromFloat((max - min))];
```

That doesn't set the X range correctly, because it just sets it to the number of points in the array, which is about 2500.  I have tried setting the xRange to to the max value in my distance array, but that really screws up the graph.

How can I have two different scales for x and y and still have the graph be correct?

Here is what it looks like when I change the xRange to be my distance, the graph goes flat:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate your min and max distance and use those to set the xRange and calculate your min and max altitude and use those to set the yRange.

Comment: I know how to calculate the max and min.  What I am having issues with is, when I change the X to be the max distance value, it makes my graph flat.  See addition above.

Comment: Check your datasource and make sure you're returning the correct values for each field (CPScatterPlotFieldX and CPScatterPlotFieldY).